# PHP how to have declare a class member?

Tags: php

Slightly confused with PHP because it does not declare object variable types.
This is simplified code which does not work. I get why I get an error but not sure how in PHP I can specify that $pb is a PushBot object and so it has methods which can be used.

```
    class Bot 
{

     public $pb;

//Constructor
 function __construct(){
     require_once('../PushBots.class.php');
     // Application ID
     $appID = '';
     // Application Secret
     $appSecret = '';
     // Push The notification with parameters
     $this ->pb = new PushBots();
     $this ->pb->App($appID, $appSecret);

     }

//Method. The $this->pb->Push() does not work
 public function sendMessage(){
        $this->pb->Push();
     }

}
```

//Client calling the class

```
$bot = new Bot();
$bot->sendMessage();
```

The error I get is :

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$'  for when the line

```
$this->pb->Push();
```

is called.

I guess its because it does not know that $pb is a PushBot object at this stage ?

Can I not declare it something like :

```
Public Pushbot $pb;
```

Comment: PHP is not a strictly typed language. Meaning, you can have either an int, a PushBots object, or any other type in any variable. You can also overwrite variables with different types. I do not generally suggest doing that however.

Comment: It has nothing to do with what type of object it is - you have a basic syntax error. Is this your actual code? Try using an editor with code highlighting, NetBeans will show you syntax errors. Edit: I see you said you simplified the code - post your ACTUAL code - the line before and after the error as well.

Comment: absolutely but how do I tell it in function sendMessage() that $pb is a PushBot and therefore has a method called Push()

Comment: @drlobo: You don't have to.  PHP can see that at runtime.  Welcome to the world of dynamic typing.  :)

Comment: I think you missed `;` somewhere

Comment: Is it Push() or push()?

Comment: @vascowhite: methods/functions are case-insensitive in PHP.

Comment: For future reference...when you post an abbreviated/simplified/stripped-down version of broken code, make sure it still shows the issue you're asking about.  Otherwise, it doesn't help track down the problem.

Comment: @webbiedave ahh, duhh, should put my brain in gear.

Answer (score 1):

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$' for when the line
```

This is a parse error, meaning your code has not even been run yet. Check your code for any sytnax errors (the code you posted does not contain the syntax error).

> how in PHP I can specify that $pb is a PushBot object

Although unrelated to the syntax error, if you were using some sort of dependency inversion you could use type-hinting to require a certain object to be passed:

```
// will cause fatal error if anything other than an object of type Pushbot is passed
function __construct(Pushbot $pb)
```

Comment: True, they are separate but I mentioned it is because (besides being better practice) if he *were* injecting then he could take advantage of some of the stricter features of PHP he seems to be craving.

Comment: Much as static typing annoys me, type hinting does have its upside.  It is kinda nice to be able to grab a `ReflectionClass` and have it tell you exactly what it needs, without having to parse a (possibly obsolete) doc comment.